# jrebel with debug mode can't update class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jrebel, hot-reload

I started the project with jrebel's debug mode. When I update the class, jrebel throws the following log exception. Even though I didn't make any changes to the class, I just added a space. It is normal to start in start mode.

```
15:01:45,667 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR Failed to transform class com/whir/rd/entryinvoice/actionsupport/InvoiceAction: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: a
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.doTransform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.transform(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.applyTransformation(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.transform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:704)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:532)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:475)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:286)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:124)
15:01:45,738 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR com.whir.rd.entryinvoice.actionsupport.InvoiceAction: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JVMTI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_REDEFINITION_HIERARCHY_CHANGED
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:703)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:530)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:474)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:284)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:123)
15:01:45,740 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR Failed to transform class com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: a
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.doTransform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.transform(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.applyTransformation(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.transform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:704)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:532)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:475)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:286)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:124)
15:01:45,777 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JVMTI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_REDEFINITION_HIERARCHY_CHANGED
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:703)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:530)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:474)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:284)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:123)
15:01:45,779 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR Failed to transform class com/whir/component/actionsupport/BaseActionSupport: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: a
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.doTransform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flw.transform(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.applyTransformation(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.transform(SourceFile:70)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:704)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:532)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:475)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:286)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:124)
15:01:45,788 ERROR [STDERR] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: ERROR com.whir.component.actionsupport.BaseActionSupport: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JVMTI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_REDEFINITION_METHOD_DELETED
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClassesImpl(Native Method)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.jvmti.MinimalInstrumentation.retransformClasses(SourceFile:149)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.flv.a(SourceFile:106)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.fkr.a(SourceFile:703)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.d(SourceFile:588)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.b(SourceFile:530)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:74)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:833)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.ao.a(SourceFile:749)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.al.a(SourceFile:474)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.m(SourceFile:513)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.l(SourceFile:284)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.b.k(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.reload.c.run(SourceFile:123)
15:01:45,847 INFO  [STDOUT] 2019-10-17 15:01:45 JRebel: Reloading class 'com.whir.rd.entryinvoice.actionsupport.InvoiceAction'.
```

This makes me very confused. Is there a conflict between jrebel and debug mode? I am using the latest version of jrebel, virtual machine oracle jrockit 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Yes JRebel should work with those debug options. I am unsure why you are getting these errors. I would need to see those logs to understand what is happening.

If you want to resolve it send me your logs to support@jrebel.com and I will be more than glad to assist further.

Answer (score -1):

My name is Curtis Johnson and I am an engineer with JRebel team at Perforce. This appears to be some kind of bug in your application that may or may not have to do directly with JRebel. You would be best served working with our support team to resolve this issue. If you can send the JRebel log ([instructions here](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/sendinglogs.html)) to support@jrebel.com, we can help you with this issue.

Comment: hello Curtis,I checked the cause of the problem. When I run jrebel from the command line, when I add debugging parameters, this problem will occur. If the debugging parameters are removed, it will return to normal. Parameters are as follows：-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5007